Easiest way to convert std::chrono::microseconds to %H%M%S
I have a std::chrono::microseconds duration that denotes the amount of microseconds that have passed since the last midnight. What's the easiest way to print it in the time format %H%M%S in c++20?
This is what AI suggests me but it's very verbose!
void print_time(std::chrono::microseconds duration) {
    // Convert microseconds to seconds
    auto duration_in_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(duration);

    // Extract hours, minutes, and seconds
    auto hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(duration_in_seconds);
    duration_in_seconds -= hours;
    auto minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(duration_in_seconds);
    duration_in_seconds -= minutes;
    auto seconds = duration_in_seconds;

    // Print the result
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << hours.count() << ":"
              << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << minutes.count() << ":"
              << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << seconds.count() << std::endl;
}

I'm quite sure it can be done in a more straightfoward way?

As of C++ 20 you can
void print_time(std::chrono::microseconds duration) {
    std::cout << std::format("{:%H:%M:%OS}", duration) << '\n';
}

Demo
Documentation for std::format
Side note: Instead of hardcoding in std::cout, you can make the function a bit more versatile by passing in the output stream as a generic std::ostream:
std::ostream& print_time(std::ostream & out,
                         std::chrono::microseconds duration) {
    out << std::format("{:%H:%M:%OS}", duration) << '\n';
    return out;
}

Now you can use the function to print to ANY stream.
Side note: Those required to use or maintaining systems requiring tools that do not support C++20 can use fmtlib to the same effect, though you can't go too far into the past because you still need bits of C++11.

Worth mentioning that fmtlib supports this too

And to add a bit more flexibility, pass the format in as a parameter.
